# What kind of martial art did Miles O'Brien get this move from?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, martial-arts

In season 4, episode 9 (Hard Time), Miles O'Brien gets annoyed with Quark's slow service and grabs hold of his hand into some sort of joint lock.

What martial art did it originate from? Did the actor contribute it or was it written this way?
[image: Miles O'Brien attacks Quark]

Answer (score 3):

## Aikido, Hapkido, or Jujitsu

This seems to be a standard "wristlock", perhaps a *supinating* one:

[image]

This is a common move in the disciplines I listed above — see [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wristlock).

(**Note:** I'm not a martial arts expert.  If someone can pin down the exact move that O'Brien is using, or can find an official reference about the level of improvisation in the scene, I'd be happy to defer to that.)

Comment: I would have guessed a wristlock like Kote Kaeshi (as in your picture and mentioned by @Tiseno as well) as well. One of my Aikido teachers noted that he was using the bar as a support, but he is not using the right center control which would mean it was heading in the direction of the Hyperflexing wristlock mentioned on the same wikipedia page (we once practiced that one on a joined aikido/ju jutsu lesson, and it would certainly give Quarks response if applied correctly). Still not sure how it ended up here, although the actor did work with Steven Seagal in Under Siege.

Answer (score 0):

In Jujutsu/Aikido it is called the Kote Gaeshi.

Comment: Do you have some sources you can add to this?